# How to format any RawRepresentable without having to access its rawValue?

Tags: swift

Let's assume we have a few structures that conform to the `RawRepresentable` protocol, with `RawValue` of various types.

```
struct Position: RawRepresentable {
    var rawValue: Int
}

struct Link: RawRepresentable {
    var rawValue: URL
}

struct Price: RawRepresentable {
    var rawValue: Double
}
```

To format these values we have to go through their `rawValue`.

```
let position = Position(rawValue: 1000)
let link = Link(rawValue: URL(string: "https://stackoverflow.com")!)
let price = Price(rawValue: 2.99)

position.rawValue.formatted(.number.grouping(.never)) // "1000"
link.rawValue.formatted(.url.scheme(.never)) // "stackoverflow.com"
price.rawValue.formatted(.currency(code: "EUR")) // "€2.99"
```

It works perfectly. But is there a more elegant way to format these values without having to access their `rawValue`? That is, in this way:

```
position.formatted(.number.grouping(.never))
link.formatted(.url.scheme(.never))
price.formatted(.currency(code: "EUR"))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want to declare `formatted` to each of your structs, You can just define `formatted` on all `RawRepresentable`s, with `FormatInput` being constrained to the `RawValue`:

```
extension RawRepresentable {
    func formatted<F>(_ format: F) -> F.FormatOutput where F: FormatStyle, F.FormatInput == RawValue {
        format.format(rawValue)
    }
}
```

This will also add this to your enums with raw values, which might not make a lot of sense. It might be better to define your own sub-protocol, make your structs conform to that protocol, and put the extension on that protocol instead:

```
protocol RawValueFormattable: RawRepresentable {}

extension RawValueFormattable {
    func formatted<F>(_ format: F) -> F.FormatOutput where F: FormatStyle, F.FormatInput == RawValue {
        format.format(rawValue)
    }
}
```

Then you can do exactly what you want:

```
position.formatted(.number.grouping(.never))
link.formatted(.url.scheme(.never))
price.formatted(.currency(code: "EUR"))
```

Note that if you want to define those parameterless `formatted` overloads, you would need to do it for each type of `RawRepresentable`/`RawValueFormattable`, e.g.

```
extension RawRepresentable where RawValue: BinaryInteger {
    func formatted() -> String {
        rawValue.formatted()
    }
}

extension RawRepresentable where RawValue: BinaryFloatingPoint {
    func formatted() -> String {
        rawValue.formatted()
    }
}

extension RawRepresentable where RawValue == URL {
    func formatted() -> String {
        rawValue.formatted()
    }
}
```